# What is the type of quasiquote that matched type parameters?

Tags: scala, scala-macros, shapeless, scala-quasiquotes

I have a quoasiquote matcher where `q"someMethod[$ts]()"` where `def someMethod[I <: shapeless.HList]()"`.

Printing `ts` gives:

```
List(shapeless.HNil)
```

or, e.g.

```
List(String, Int)
```

Then I try to assign:

```
val types: List[scala.reflect.api.Types.Type] = ts
```

that causes compiler error:

```
[error] type mismatch;
[error]  found   : List[_125.u.Tree] where val _125: scala.reflect.api.QuasiquoteCompat.TypeAppliedExtractor{val u: OpTreeContext.this.c.universe.type}
[error]  required: List[Context.this.c.universe.Type]
```

How to compose `List[scala.reflect.api.Types.Type]` from `ts`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your error message states, `ts` is a list of trees. More specifically, these will be [type trees](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Trees%24TypeTreeApi), and you can extract their types with the `tpe` method:

```
val types: List[scala.reflect.api.Types#Type] = ts.map(_.tpe)
```

Note that I'm using a type projection, since `Types` is neither a package nor an object, so `Types.Type` won't work.